# Javascript submit() of the POST method form does not seem to work

Tags: forms, post, submit

Trying to submit a form with Javascript that has the method attribute set to POST does not seem to work. I tried every workaround that I found on the web but to no avail. I'd like to know if there's a way to do this or must I resort to GET?
Using AJAX would be extremely ugly here as the actual form has upwards of 50 form elements.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function formSubmit()
{
document.getElementById("method").value="save";
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Submit form" button to submit the form.</p>

<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="hidden" id="method" />
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Submit form" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

1. First workaround I found said add the onsubmit="return false;"
2. Another said add the document.getElementById("method").value="save";
3. Yet another said replace onclick="formSubmit()"  with onclick="this.form.submit()"

However, nothing works.
Any suggestions?
TIA

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?  I copy and pasted your example into Firefox 9 and it worked fine.  It tried to post to the proper page.  What happens when you click the button??

Comment: Tried it in Chrome and in IE and it worked.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. For the moment I'm running this in Kubuntu and I'm using Firefox 9.0.1 and Chromium 15.0.874.106. Here's a link to the W3 try it page, be sure to add the method="post" to the form definiton: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_submit

Comment: When I add the method="post" attribute to the try it now page I linked above, the names do not get sent over. However, if change it to method="get" or remove it altogether then the names are sent just fine.

Comment: OK, I tried this locally and it does indeed work. So it's just a bug with the W3 web site. :( Thanks Jordan, and sorry about the noise. Stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question until tomorrow, so I guess we can consider this case closed.

Comment: Ah.  I didn't realize you were trying it ON the w3 page.  yeah their page was not set to receive posts only gets so that wouldn't work.  I had copied and tried it locally which is why it worked for me too.